# How to get sum of two different columns with Laravel Query Builder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get the sum of two different columns using Laravel query builder, the plain SQL Query below works just fine, but I can't get it to work with the Laravel Query.

```
SELECT SUM(logins_sun + logins_mon) FROM users_stats WHERE id = 7; // returns: 1034
```

Here's what I have tried.

```
$stats = DB::table('users_stats')->where('id', '=', '7')->sum('logins_sun', '+', 'logins_mon'); // returns: 587.0
```

And here is my DB structure.

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | logins_sun | logins_mon |
+----+------------+------------+
|  7 |     587    |     447    |
+----+------------+------------+
```

It was supposed to return *1034* but the Laravel Query is returning only the last value *587.0* .

How can I get it working?

Comment: If you want to have the sum of both columns separately, you may use [subquery joins](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins)

Answer (score 25):

You can try with the `sum()` method like:

```
DB::table('users_stats')
    ->where('id', '7')
    ->sum(\DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon'));
```

Comment: Is "\" neccessary? I have tried it without and it works!

Answer (score 12):

`sum` is an aggregate function and only takes one argument. It will sum the values of each row in a column. In your case, the query only returns one row, so the sum is just the value of that one column (the first argument passed to `sum()`). There may be some better way to do it, but I think you should be able to use a raw expression to return the sum of the two columns.

```
$stats = DB::table('users_stats')
             ->select(DB::raw('logins_sun + logins_mon'))
             ->where('id', '=', '7');
```

Answer (score 2):

Try passing a callback to the sum() and do the addition there like:

```
$stats = DB::table('users_stats')->where('id', '=', '7')->sum(function ($row) {
    return $row->logins_sun + $row->logins_mon;
});
```

Comment: Strange: when I apply that, I get the following error: "`strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given`"

Comment: the same problem here `stripos(): Argument #1 ($haystack) must be of type string, Closure given`

Answer (score 1):

You can run direct raw sql in laravel with the following way :

```
$sql = "SELECT SUM(logins_sun + logins_mon) FROM users_stats WHERE id = :ID";

$result = DB::select($sql,['ID'=>7]);
```